# Button border radius and cursor

Tags: css, html, button, webkit

CSS border radius does affect button rendering (I see it's round form), but does not affect how it interacts with the user (I still can click button outside its border). How should I fix it?

I see the behavior in Chrome.

```
button
{
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: red; /*transparent;*/ /* It's actually red and ROUND. */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 73px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 73px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 73px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 73px;
    width: 146px; height: 146px;

    background-image: url('leftarrow.png');
}
```

[image: This effect is unwanted.]

Regards,

Comment: I'm trying to avoid pointer cursor at corners. Will attach a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually "broken", since it's the way it's supposed to work, so you can't really fix it, all elements render as rectangles in the browser (if you inspect the round button, you'll see it covers a rectangular area)

You can either (as @Greg pointed out) use the `<area>` tag, or you can use JavaScript to do the following:

- If outside the circle coords, show a regular mouse icon; If inside, show a pointer
- If outside the circle coords, return false in the onclick method; If inside, return true.

Comment: OK, but what about a good workaround? I don't like <area> and mousemove event handling.

Comment: The only workaround that I can think of, that doesn't involve those solutions would be to create enough elements to cover the desired "unclickable" area (which corresponds to the area not included in the circle), but that's even worse than adding an <area> tag or doing it with JavaScript in my opinion. If you want to avoid JS, <area> is the way to go, as @Greg suggested.

Comment: By the way, the SVG solution proposed below for @Grzegorz Łuszczek is also valid, but older browsers might not support it (doing a quick test, latest IE, FF and Chrome do support it, but IE8 and below, doesn't)

Comment: Thank you. On second thoughts I've flipped a bit and decided to leave the behavior unchanged at all, saying it's finger-oriented interface (which is actually not completely untrue).

Comment: i realize this is old, but for people stumbling by: **this is a WebKit (safari/chrome) bug**... the spec says: " the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept pointer events on behalf of the element" (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping).  Meaning **this is "BROKEN"** here are the relevant bug filings i could find if you want to press the issues;   CHROME: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100004     SAFARI/WEBKIT: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95373

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this instead. Then use onclick event.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only solution is use inline SVG and tag `circle`.

I guess that browser render div as rectangle, and dont care about border radius (because this corner still belongs to rectangle).