# Events in the corners with border-radius

Tags: javascript, hover, css

How do I keep events from firing in the corners outside of the border set by `border-radius` (white corners)?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/daykkin/C2dwX/)

```
<div class="circle">
   <a href="#"><span></span></a>
</div>

.circle {
    border-radius:100px;
}
span {
    display:block;
    background:#000;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:100px;
}

$(".circle").click(function() {
   alert("GOD! WHY I'AM WORK ON WHITE CORNERS!?! KILL ME PLEASE!");
});
```

Comment: What are you meaning ?  you want rounded corners with Jquery ? Or you wanne have differnt color of corners ?

Comment: If you are asking how to make it so that the border radius is only present on click: `$('.circle').on('click', function() { $(this).css('border-radius','100px') });`. You will have to remove the css that gives it 100px border-radius by default

Comment: Sorry guys, i am updated the post . In first time in here :)

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking, if it isn't what I commented above?

Comment: No no. I want to disable any js events on white corners (see example).

Comment: aaah i understand your question now :D

Comment: According to comments http://stackoverflow.com/a/9760859/844923 this is a bug in webkit. bug reports: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100004 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95373

Answer (score 0):

Use html tags map and erea to create a circle ;-)

example comming up ..

Comment: In fact realisation sit deep on sliders script, and i just lose many resourses to rewriting it. Is any simple way to unbind js events on corners in div with border-radius?

Comment: Yes, but cant find it its a few line of jquery code thats takes your stuff and all the tags what needed and makes only the circle, its a plugin but cant find it