# overflow:hidden not working with border-radius in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rounded-corners

I'm trying to make a circle-shaped image with an overlay that shows on hover. However, the "hitbox" of hovering (and clicking) is incorrect, as shown in the snippet below.

This issue seems to only occur in Chrome (not sure about Safari). **I've found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5736503/5532169) [fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16878279/5532169) on the Internet, but none of them worked.** [JSFiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/zypA1310/r7qhzneg/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".circle").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
});
```

```css
#canvas {
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #eee;
}
.circle {
 position: absolute;
 width: 25%;
 padding-bottom: 25%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
 /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987370/5532169*/
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206004/5532169*/
 z-index: 1;
 /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296258/5532169*/
 -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
 /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/16878347/5532169*/
 -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);
}
.mid {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}
.inner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.inner>* {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hover:hover {
 opacity: 100;
 transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 72%;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #08f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
 <div id="div1" class="circle">
  <div class="mid">
  <div class="inner">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x320/000/fff" alt="">
   <div class="hover">
    <span>Hello World!</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Tested in Firefox 57, works without problem. IE and Edge were tested already, so it's a Chrome-/webkit-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks in HTML are square defined by position (x, y) and size (width, height) so the browser can have a simplified idea of what is on the page and interact with. So even with border-radius, mask-image, etc... your `.circle` div is still a square with coming drawn within.

[image]

To avoid that, you can't use a dynamic selector like `:hover` because it will use the shape of the div and that is a square. You need to use javascript to detect mouse position when hovering your block and with that execute an animation (with sinus and cosinus calculation).

You can get the mouse position with something like this :

```
<div class="circle" onmouseover="hoverFunction(e)"></div>
<script>
function hoverFunction(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
}
</script>
```

I also found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480133/how-can-i-get-an-objects-absolute-position-on-the-page-in-javascript) talking about getting elements position on the page.

Comment: But then, why do Firefox, IE, and Edge handle this correctly? I've actually found [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3248734/5532169) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9760692#comment16648543_9760859) claiming this to be a bug specific to WebKit (and Chrome). Do I really have to solve a styling issue with JavaScript? I'd prefer some CSS fix if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can change only .circle class these properties:

```
width: 26%;
padding-bottom: 26%;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) -webkit prefixed version is only required for Chrome 4. Are you sure, have you tested this? Because it's not working on my end.